# Prove Stereographic projection is a homeomorphism from Sphere except North Pole to Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, stereographic-projections

I'm self-studying exercises of Jones in Reference and I'm stuck at 1D which is the following;

### 1D

[image]

### My question

The (standard) proof that I know (for instance [Q4 of this note](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Eguillou/f12/351WS5Soln.pdf)) does not seem to involve the notions of the distance or the angle... So I was not sure how to go about in this exercise. Could anyone give me some hints?

### Reference

Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: Did you try finding the distance between $Q_1$ and $Q_2$? If so, where did you get stuck? I don't think there's a better way than direct calculation.

Comment: @TheoBendit, oh, I was using the Euclidean distance to do that part, so I didn't see how the angle involved in the question, but maybe that was wrong?

To anser your question, yes, I worked out the expression of the distance based on the inverse stereographic projection s.t. $\pi^{-1}: (x, y) \mapsto (\frac{x}{z \bar{z} + 1}, \frac{y}{z \bar{z} + 1}, \frac{z \bar{z} - 1}{z \bar{z} + 1})$ where $\bar{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate.

Comment: When looking at unit vectors, the Euclidean distance between them, their dot product, and the angle subtended from $0$, are all readily related to each other. From expanding $\|u - v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - 2u \cdot v$, and recalling $\|u\|^2 = \|v\|^2 = 1$, we get a simple linear relationship between the square distance and the dot product. The dot product is, of course, just $\cos$ of the angle subtended. Why they specifically wanted the angle from the distance, I have honestly no idea what they're aiming for.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your clarification! That makes sense!